# Go to tag with special attribute in XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to go to a special parent tag who has a special attribut

XML :

```
<Rang type="header">
       <Cellule>
            <Paragraphe>Modifications</Paragraphe>
       </Cellule>
       <Cellule>
            <Paragraphe>You need to use</Paragraphe>
        </Cellule>
</Rang>
<Rang type="normal">
        <Cellule>
            <Paragraphe>Buil</Paragraphe>
        </Cellule>
        <Cellule>
            <Paragraphe>
                n°6650 cerfa n°10867*04
            </Paragraphe>
        </Cellule>
</Rang>
```

If the `type` equal `header`, i want to go in to get values. If type equal `normal`, i want the same.

Comment: What's the output you want to achieve? Where is the XSLT you tried?

Comment: My output is HTML, i just put few lines of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what output you need. But this XSLT does have a template for both of your `Rang` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Rang[@type='header']">
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="Cellule/Paragraphe"/>
        </h1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Rang[@type='normal']">
        <xsl:value-of select="'some value'"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can select both `header` and `normal` with a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Rang[@type='header']| Rang[@type='normal']">
        <!-- select you values -->
</xsl:template>
```